# Pages and Keynote URL Scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, url-scheme, keynote

Does anybody know, what is the URL Scheme for Pages and Keynote? I need it to open my 'Pages' App and 'Keynote' App from a button I have created. If there is no an URL Scheme for Keynote and Pages, what should I do to open these two apps?
I really need your help.
Thank you very much!

Comment: `open /path/to/your/file` will let the OS figure out how to open that file. It won't work for everything but it will work for pages and keynote files.

Comment: I didn't understand you! What file should I have to open? What I want to open is my Keynote or Pages app using URL Scheme

Answer (score -1):

Please refer below article on open different apps!

https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/

Use openURL function to achieve the task.

Comment: This doesn't help with OP's question about the schemes of *Pages* and *Keynote*.